# Cadastrando atributos de classes diferentes em uma mesma View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma classe Professor que possui um Usuário, e quero cadastrar os campos de Usuário na View de professor.

Como posso estar fazer isso

```
public  class Usuario 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Matricula { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

}


public class Professor 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Exitem varias formas de resolver isso, mas uma dica, é assistir a aula do link abaixo. https://mva.microsoft.com/pt-br/training-courses/aspnet-mvc-intermedirio-12103?l=jZUi7sRIB_8004984382

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se os campos estiverem dentro da mesma view, crie os campos normalmente na view, referenciando o objeto do model.

Um edit pro campo "Nome" do objeto "Usuario" na view Edit/Create do Controller "Professor" por exemplo ficaria assim:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Usuario.Nome)
```